# Download of large files does not work

Tags: php, download

Hey i have following code to download a large file but the download does stop everytime without finish the download

```
function download($file)
{
    include('logger.php5');
    $log = new Logging();
    $log->lfile('download.log');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 86400);
    //header('Location: '.$file);
    $filesize = filesize($file);
    $filename = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
    $filext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $mime = include('mime.php5');

    $log->lwrite(ini_get('max_execution_time'));
    $log->lwrite(sprintf('%s %s %s %s', $filename, $filext, $mime[$filext], human_filesize($filesize)));
    $log->lclose();
    @ob_end_clean();
    session_write_close();
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type: ".$mime[$filext]);
    header("Content-Disposition: ".
     (!strpos($HTTP_USER_AGENT,"MSIE 5.5")?"attachment; ":"").
     "filename=".$filename);
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".$filesize);
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    $done = readfile_chunked($file);
}

function readfile_chunked($filename,$retbytes=true) { 
   $chunksize = 1*(1024*1024); // how many bytes per chunk 
   $buffer = ''; 
   $cnt =0; 
   // $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb'); 
   $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb'); 
   if ($handle === false) { 
       return false; 
   } 
   while (!feof($handle)) { 
       $buffer = fread($handle, $chunksize); 
       echo $buffer; 
       ob_flush(); 
       flush(); 
       if ($retbytes) { 
           $cnt += strlen($buffer); 
       } 
   } 
       $status = fclose($handle); 
   if ($retbytes && $status) { 
       return $cnt; // return num. bytes delivered like readfile() does. 
   } 
   return $status;
}
```

Each time i call the script the download start up but stops after 400MB, the file itself is 778MB big.

Someone can see a problem with the code?

**UPDATE**

after try to log the return value of `readfile_chunked`it feels like the script gets stoped not the download itself. Because i cant get a log entry after the `readfile_chunked` call.

Comment: all headers are set inside the `download` function outside are just security stuff to identify the right file

Comment: yeah the correct headers get sent.

Comment: When you say the download stops, do you mean that the client only receives 400MB? Or do you mean the `readfile_chunked` function returns a count of 400MB? Or both?

Comment: the client gets the header 778MB but after around 400MB, the scripts seems just to stop. i tried to write a log line after `readfile_chunked`but it does not excuted.

Comment: So then most likely the runtime is terminating the script. Is anything logged?

Comment: i dont have access to any log files then my `download.log` so i cant tell you

Answer (score -1):

It could be a problem with the `filesize` function in PHP. There are known bugs for big file size reading and as you're sending it with the file as an header I would suggest you to try the script without using this line:

```
 header("Content-Length: ".$filesize);
```

Oh and maybe you can take a look at this line:

```
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

I think the encoding should be checked for each file. Like this:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);

//check to see if the mime-type starts with 'text'
return substr(finfo_file($finfo, $filename), 0, 4) == 'text';
```

If it's a textfile you should use ASCII ofcourse. Has nothing to do with the question but I think it's an useful addition to your script :)